# Cannot resolve method 'getRef(int)'

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUlru.png) I want to delete data from firebase using .removeValue(); but can't fetch the key inside child using .child(getRef(position).getKey()); it says "Cannot resolve method 'getRef(int)'"

I tried to get the key using getter & setter in model class, but that too didn't work!
Android Studio it does not resolve getRef(int) method. Here is the code:

```
public class RecyclerContactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerContactAdapter.ViewHolder> {



Context context;

ArrayList<User> list;

DataSnapshot snapshot;

FirebaseFirestore firestore;
FirebaseAuth auth;

DatabaseReference reference;




//for search
public void setFilteredList(ArrayList<User> filteredList){
    this.list = filteredList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

public RecyclerContactAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User>list){

     this.context = context;
     this.list = list;


    }




    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.contact_row, parent, false);


        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        User user = list.get(position);
//        String id1 = list.get(position).getKey();

        holder.name.setText(user.getName());
        holder.chn.setText(user.getChn());
        holder.shn.setText(user.getShn());
        holder.phone.setText(user.getPhone());

        holder.hostel_optn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("HostelSwappingDatabase")
                    .child(getRef(position).getKey())
                    .removeValue();


            }
        });

        holder.setIsRecyclable(false);


    }




    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }


//
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

//
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView name, chn, shn, phone;
        ImageView hostel_optn;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView){
           super(itemView);

           name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
           chn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chn);
           shn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.shn);
           phone = itemView.findViewById(R.id.phone);


           hostel_optn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hostel_optn);

        }








    }

}
```

Comment: You're not calling getRef on anything, so it defaults to being called on your Adapter class.  And that class doesn't have a getRef function.  Either you're missing a function or you're missing the variable you wanted to call it on.

Comment: then how can I delete data from firebase in this case? plz help me with an example code!

Comment: plz help me, am trying it for very long @GabeSechan

Comment: `getRef()` should be called on a [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#getRef()) object, that's the reason why you get that error. However, if you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-a-record-from-firestore-on-a-recylerview-left-right-swipe-d65d993f0baf) or even this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-multiple-records-from-firestore-using-recyclerview-multi-selection-96108e4c6166) might help.

Answer (score 0):

To delete any data instance from Firebase, one must implement FirebaseRecyclerAdapter as mentioned [here](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-android/database/readme/)

also get help from this video, if required [click here](https://youtu.be/ePKC5ZEqeNY).